# Can @google-cloud/logging be used in Ionic4/Angular8/Firebase client app? How to fix module import errors

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-logging

I want to use nodejs-logging in an app using Ionic 4, Angular 8, and Firebase to write logs to StackDriver.

In the app root I do the following:

1. npm install @google-cloud/logging
2. Go to @google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.d.ts, and add this import statement: `import {Long} from "protobufjs"`;
3. Do the same in @google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.config.d.ts
4. Build the Ionic app

I am, however, getting a list of Module not found errors from many different core node modules: crypto,child_process, fs, os, net, path, http, http2, stream, tls, and zlib.

Error message as below:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClientBrowser.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in
>   '/home/pam/strata1/strata_forms_app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src'
>   ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   '/home/pam/strata1/strata_forms_app/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
>   ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   '/home/pam/strata1/strata_forms_app/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth'
>   ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node/crypto.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/home/pam/strata1/strata_forms_app/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@opencensus/propagation-stackdriver/build/src/stackdriver-format.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in
>   '/home/pam/strata1/strata_forms_app/node_modules/@opencensus/propagation-stackdriver/build/src' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@opencensus/propagation-stackdriver/build/src/v1.js

I am new to configuring webpack, but I tried adding a webpack.config.js file to `@google-cloud/logging/build/src` as well as to `<ionic_app_root>./src` containing the following config changes:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    node: {
      console: false,
      global: true,
      process: true,
      __filename: 'mock',
      __dirname: 'mock',
      Buffer: true,
      setImmediate: true,
      child_process: 'empty',
      crypto: 'empty',
      fs: 'empty',
      os: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      path: 'empty',
      http: 'empty',
      http2: 'empty',
      stream: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      zlib: 'empty',
    }
  };
```

Given that this library is described as a StackDriver node.js client library I expected it would work in an Ionic4 + Angular8 + Firebase app.

```
  - Node.js version: 11.10.0
  - npm version: 6.7.0
  - `@google-cloud/logging` version: 5.2.2
  - AngularCLI: 8.2.3
  - typescript: 3.5.3
  - webpack 4.39.2
```

Comment: This question may has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326989/adding-google-cloud-logging-in-typescript-functions-project-gives-error/47336034#47336034

Comment: Harif, thanks but the information post you mention is no longer relevant - it may have been true 1year 9 months ago but in the latest @google-cloud/logging version 5.2.2, the node module typescript declaration files are provided in build/proto.

Comment: This is the response I got from library maintainers on Github FYI: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/issues/566

Answer (score 3):

As is mentioned on the response you received in GitHub [1]:

"We are in progress of making it possible to use the libraries with Webpack but it will likely take some more time. The reason for that is that this library uses gRPC (sends protocol buffers over HTTP/2) which cannot be webpacked easily. While that work is in progress, you can try using our less complicated library https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/src/apis/logging (which sends plain JSON over HTTP/1 and thus is webpackable). Alternatively, take care of your logging calls on the server side."

Google Api's team

I'm sharing the answer provided in Github in order to help another developers with similar issue.

[1] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/issues/566